# No content just background , why is there a scroll bar?

Tags: css, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am really stuck on a small issue im having on my website.

Whenever i add a viewport to my HTML , it creates a scroll bar even though theres no content that is overflowing.

I am using Bootstrap as the CSS framework.

```
  body {
  /* Location of the image */
  background-image: url(http://www.haristechnology.com/images/footer_lodyas.png);

  /* Background image is centered vertically and horizontally at all times */
  background-position: center center;

  /* Background image doesn't tile */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  /* Background image is fixed in the viewport so that it doesn't move when 
     the content's height is greater than the image's height */
  background-attachment: fixed;

  /* This is what makes the background image rescale based
     on the container's size */
  background-size: cover;

  /* Set a background color that will be displayed
     while the background image is loading */
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
.navbar-default {
    font-size: 26px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    border-width: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(12, 245, 229, 0.59);
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: rgba(20, 250, 39, 1);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#nav.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #000000;
}

.custom{
    margin-top:15%;
}
```

this is the HTML

```
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title> HarisTechnology</title>
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
      <link href="//www.google-analytics.com" rel="dns-prefetch">
      <link href="http://haristechnology.com/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/img/icons/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
      <link href="http://haristechnology.com/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/img/icons/touch.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed">
      <meta name="description" content="HarisTechnology &#8211; Website">
            <script type="text/javascript">
            window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"http:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/72x72\/","ext":".png","source":{"concatemoji":"http:\/\/haristechnology.com\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.2.2"}};
            !function(a,b,c){function d(a){var c=b.createElement("canvas"),d=c.getContext&&c.getContext("2d");return d&&d.fillText?(d.textBaseline="top",d.font="600 32px Arial","flag"===a?(d.fillText(String.fromCharCode(55356,56812,55356,56807),0,0),c.toDataURL().length>3e3):(d.fillText(String.fromCharCode(55357,56835),0,0),0!==d.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data[0])):!1}function e(a){var c=b.createElement("script");c.src=a,c.type="text/javascript",b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)}var f,g;c.supports={simple:d("simple"),flag:d("flag")},c.DOMReady=!1,c.readyCallback=function(){c.DOMReady=!0},c.supports.simple&&c.supports.flag||(g=function(){c.readyCallback()},b.addEventListener?(b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",g,!1),a.addEventListener("load",g,!1)):(a.attachEvent("onload",g),b.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===b.readyState&&c.readyCallback()})),f=c.source||{},f.concatemoji?e(f.concatemoji):f.wpemoji&&f.twemoji&&(e(f.twemoji),e(f.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
    display: inline !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    height: 1em !important;
    width: 1em !important;
    margin: 0 .07em !important;
    vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
    background: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='mcafeesecure_css-css'  href='http://haristechnology.com/wp-content/plugins/mcafee-secure/assets/common.css?ver=1.0' media='' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='normalize-css'  href='http://haristechnology.com/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/normalize.css?ver=1.0' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='html5blank-css'  href='http://haristechnology.com/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/style.css?ver=1.0' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://haristechnology.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://haristechnology.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://haristechnology.com/wp-content/plugins/mcafee-secure/assets/common.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://haristechnology.com/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/js/lib/conditionizr-4.3.0.min.js?ver=4.3.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://haristechnology.com/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/js/lib/modernizr-2.7.1.min.js?ver=2.7.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://haristechnology.com/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/js/scripts.js?ver=1.0.0'></script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://haristechnology.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/favicon.ico"/>
  <style type="text/css">
    .screen-reader-response {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
        <script>
         conditionizr.config({
             assets: 'http://haristechnology.com/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable',
             tests: {}
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body class="home page page-id-34 page-template-default logged-in index">
      <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
      <div style="background-color:transparent;border:0px;border-radius:0;margin-top:-1%;width:100%; height:25%;"class="well">
      <!--Navigation Starts -->
      <div style="margin-top:1%;"id='nav'>
         <img class="animated bounceInUp" src="images/banner.png" style="width:100%;" />
         <br>
         <br>
         <nav class="navbar navbar-default animated fadeIn" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" style="background-color:#FF1919 !important;" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
                  data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.haristechnology.com/">HarisTechnology</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
               <ul id="menu-default" class="nav navbar-nav"><li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-34 current_page_item menu-item-36 active"><a title="Home" href="http://haristechnology.com/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-41"><a title="Products" href="http://haristechnology.com/productspage">Products</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-42"><a title="Contact" href="http://haristechnology.com/contact-2">Contact</a></li>
</ul>            </div>
      </div>
      </nav>
      <!--Navigation ENDS -->
      <!--Content Starts -->
      <!-- /header -->



                <div class="jumbotron" style="margin-left: 0%; border-radius: 0; margin-top: 0%; width: 100%;">
<h1>Hello</h1>
</div>

        <div style="background-color:#AAF200;margin-left:0%;border-radius:0;margin-top:0%;width:100%"class="jumbotron">
<center>
<h2>
Website under construction.
</h2>
</center>
</div>
<h3 class="pull-right" style="color:#cde2bd;">Developed by HarisTechnology.</h3>
<!--Footer ENDS -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var sa = document.createElement('script'); sa.type = 'text/javascript'; sa.async = true;
    sa.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://cdn' : 'http://cdn') + '.ywxi.net/js/1.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(sa, s);
  })();
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://haristechnology.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/jquery.form.min.js?ver=3.51.0-2014.06.20'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var _wpcf7 = {"loaderUrl":"http:\/\/haristechnology.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/contact-form-7\/images\/ajax-loader.gif","sending":"Sending ..."};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://haristechnology.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=4.1.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://haristechnology.com/wp-content/plugins/bootstrap-for-contact-form-7/assets/scripts.min.js?ver=1.1.0'></script>
<!-- analytics -->
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-62813338-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var sa = document.createElement('script'); sa.type = 'text/javascript'; sa.async = true;
    sa.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://cdn' : 'http://cdn') + '.ywxi.net/js/1.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(sa, s);
  })();
</script>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: This problem is only happening in Chrome so far and not Internet Explorer?

Comment: Could you create JSFiddle or something else?

Comment: I think your tag structure is messed up... looks like one too many closing DIV tags inside your NAV tag

Comment: I dont think i can create a jsfiddle as my site is on wordpress. the site is http://www.haristechnology.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your div#nav. When you animate the logo up from the bottom, Chrome isn't calculating the height properly and you're getting a ton of overflow at the bottom of the document.

In your css for div#nav, add `overflow: hidden;` and your problem will go away.

Comment: Thanks , fixed! How did you manage to find out that this was causing the error?

Comment: I scratched my head over the same problem a few months back when using WOW js with animate.css. The second I saw your site, I had a feeling it was the same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no viewport for the body and that is most likely causing the issue.   Typically, a cover image is set for a div.   I am not 100% sure thats it, but have you tried it without the background?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess based on what you've said, and without a fiddle; but it sounds like an issue with overflow. Have you tried just adding overflow:hidden, or overflow:visible, to your CSS?

Comment: I have tried overflow:hidden but it's not an ideal solution as i have pages that do have content overflowing, although overflow:hidden does fix this issue on certain pages but at the same time causes problems for the pages that do have content overflowing as you cannot scroll down. , the website is haristechnology.com